# error in entitymanager commit for date type due to use of reserved word as column name

Tags: java, database, eclipselink, derby

Im using eclipseLink with derby DB and I encounter the following error when I use the 
commit (`entityManager.getTransaction().commit();`) the field **from** is defined in the
entity with date of java util .
what is wrong here?

the code which is entering the data is :

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
date = parsedDate.parse((String) memberValue);
```

member value contain the date with the following value

```
"from": "2012-12-03"
"to": "2012-12-03"
```

the entity look as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "f1_LeaveRequest")
public class LeaveRequest {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "leaverequest_id")
    private String id;
    private String type;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private java.util.Date from;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

the error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 47.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO f1_LeaveRequest (leaverequest_id, FROM, LENGTH, STATE, TO, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the field with `@Column` annotation and provide a different name for it.

```
@Column(name ="from_timestamp")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date from;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that is because `FROM` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Try renaming your field to `fromDate` or `fromTimestamp` or whatsoever and see if the problem is solved that way.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` is a reserved keyword. Use something meaningful, like `fromTime`.